# Input/Output context of intent in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

**Hello World!**

I need your help in dialogflow v2.
I have to ask and get user informations like gender, last-name, first-name, maiden-name.

Diagram of my intents

[image]

List of intents

[image]

Detail of an intent

[image]

After the welcome intent, I have the Gender intent. After that, there is the last-name intent.
If the user is Mr, then we have last-name and after the first-name.
For Mme, we want the married-name. We ask if the married-name and the maiden-name are same. If not, we need the maiden-name. And at the end, we ask for the first-name.

In the first scenario, dialogflow always ask the first-name at the end.
For the second scenario, when dialogflow ask the first-name, it doesn't understand the answer.
In last scenario, when the user answer for maiden-name, dialogflow doesn't understand.

Have you got an idee to resolve this?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [slots](https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters) to collect the parameters like gender, name, etc in a single intent
[image]

Check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424936/how-to-trigger-multiple-intent-in-webhook-api-ai/51426203?noredirect=1#comment89825367_51426203). I have posted something that might help you.
Recognizing non-English/American names have an issue with the Dialogflow.